# SMTPServerDisconnected: please run connect() first error on Open edX bitnami installation

Tags: python, django, smtp, edx

I have installed Open edX bitnami ami and testing it. I am facing problem with smtp email configuration. I followed the instructions here: [Bitnami Open edX - How to configure outbound email settings](https://wiki.bitnami.com/Applications/Bitnami_Open_edX#How_to_configure_outbound_email_settings.3f)
But that did not work. Email was not being sent and I could not trace the reason for this by seeing the log files. Then I followed the configurations here: [Enable SMTP for EDX (Production Stack)](https://github.com/CDOT-EDX/ProductionStackDocs/wiki/Enable-SMTP-for-EDX-(Production-Stack)) and configured `postfix` with `mandrill` smtp mail service. From the server this command works:

```
sendemail -f registration@myedx.com -t mymail@gmail.com -m "Message Body" -u "Message Subject"
```

But form the `edX` instance I am getting error. the `edx.log` file looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/edx/edx-platform/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 109, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/edx/edx-platform/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 77, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/edx/edx-platform/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/http.py", line 41, in inner
    return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/edx/edx-platform/common/djangoapps/student/views.py", line 1890, in password_reset
    domain_override=request.get_host())
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/edx/edx-platform/common/djangoapps/student/forms.py", line 72, in save
    send_mail(subject, email, from_email, [user.email])
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/edx/edx-platform/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 61, in send_mail
    connection=connection).send()
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/edx/edx-platform/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 248, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/edx/edx-platform/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 85, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/edx/edx-platform/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 50, in open
    self.connection.ehlo()
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 413, in ehlo
    self.putcmd(self.ehlo_msg, name or self.local_hostname)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 341, in putcmd
    self.send(str)
  File "/opt/bitnami/python/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 333, in send
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected('please run connect() first')
SMTPServerDisconnected: please run connect() first
```

Any idea how to solve this issue? Or how can I activate smtp email in bitnami `edX` instance?